# How to show this bipartite graph has a matching saturating X?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

> Let $G$ a bipartite graph with partitions $X$, $Y$ such that all degrees in $X$ are at least one, and if $x\in X$ has an edge to $y$ then $d(x)\geq d(y)$.
>
> Show that there's a matching saturating X.

I think I need to use Hall's theorem, but my attempts to show Hall's condition holds for such graphs always ended up in cyclic arguments.

Also, I've noted that if $k$ vertices from $X$ share a neighbour, their neighbourhood has size at least $k$ (the neighbour has degree $\geq k$, thus all of the vertices have degree at least $k$), yet I'm not sure how to use it to show Hall's condition in general.

(Note: this is *not* the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969189/halls-marriage-theorem-in-bipartite-graph), as here we have $d(x)\geq d(y)$ guaranteed only if $x$ has an edge to $y$)

Comment: I don't believe the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969189/halls-marriage-theorem-in-bipartite-graph) linked at duplicate is the same as this one.
Namely, here we have *for $x$, $y$ neighbours* $d(x)\geq d(y)$, not necessarily for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$.

Comment: Apologies for closing your question, the comments under the dupe target sort of confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$, denote the neighbourhood of $A$ by $B$.

Consider the graph induced by $A$ and $B$.

The sum over every edge $\{a,b\}$  in the graph of $\frac{1}{\deg(a)}$ gives us the number of vertices in $A$.

The sum over every edge $\{a,b\}$ in the graph of $\frac{1}{\deg(b)}$ gives us the number of vertices in $B$.

The second sum is larger than the first because the summand corresponding to each edge is larger in the second sum.